# Ionic Push on Android: unexpected error occured

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use Ionic Push notifications on android, but every time I got the following error: 

`Ionic Push:, (debug) unexpected error occured.
Ionic Push:, [object Object]`

I'm using Genymotion as my emulator, with Google Play Services installed (https://stevenkideckel.wordpress.com/2014/12/27/how-to-install-google-play-services-on-genymotion/). Testing on a real device is not working as well.

Also, I'm using this push plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push), and installed like this: 

`ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="my-gcm-project-number"`

My push code look's like this:

```js
var push = new Ionic.Push({
    'debug': true,

    'pluginConfig': {
        'android': {
            'senderID': 'my-project-number',
            'iconColor': '#343434'
        }
    }
});

push.register(function(token) {
    console.log('Device token:', token.token);
    push.saveToken(token);
});
```

I already configured my Ionic app using: 

`ionic config set dev_push false
ionic push --google-api-key my-google-api-key
ionic config set gcm_key <my-gcm-project-number>`

I tried to search for similar problemas but never found a solution.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: so do you get device id for push notification on real time

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. My "console.log('Device token:', token.token);" is never called.

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-push-not-working-on-android/52636 check this one hope it will help you

Comment: Yes, already have checked this link, but did not worked for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

When I published my app and testing on a real Android device downloading the app from Google Play, it worked.

A few things to try if you are getting this problem:

**Remove and add again the push plugin:**

```
ionic plugin remove phonegap-plugin-push
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="my-gcm-project-number"
```

Also:

- Generate a new project number and API key on Google Console;
- Check `.io-config.json` to check if your keys and numbers are correct;
- Make sure your dev push is off: `ionic config set dev_push false`;
- Set your GCM key on Ionic IO: `ionic config set gcm_key <your-gcm-project-number>`;
- Check (and make it again if needed) your build profiles on Ionic IO;

Also check this answer: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-push-not-working-on-android/52636/2

Hope this help someone.